# How to make wrapper around TraceSource class thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, logging, trace

I have written a wrapper (Custom Logger class) around TraceSource class to have more control over the way other developers will use this custom Logger and log data/messages at various levels.

Below is the code with implementation just for verbose, error and info levels.

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private const int DEF_ERROR_EVENT_ID = 2;
    private const int DEF_INFORMATION_EVENT_ID = 4;
    private const int DEF_DEBUG_EVENT_ID = 5;
    private static TraceSource source = null;

    public Logger(string nameOfComponent)
    {
         source = new TraceSource(nameOfComponent);
    }

    public  void LogDebug(Type type, string methodName)
    {
        if (type!=null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(type.ToString());
        source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, DEF_DEBUG_EVENT_ID, string.Format("{0}.{1}",type.ToString(),methodName));
    }


    public  void LogError(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) && ex == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(message, ex.ToString());
        source.TraceData(TraceEventType.Error, DEF_ERROR_EVENT_ID, message, ex);
    }

    public  void LogInformation(string message)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
        source.TraceInformation(message);
    }
  }
```

I'm initializing a static variable "source" in the Logger class' non-default constructor (given the fact that this code is going to run in a multi-threaded environment) is this practice fine in terms of thread-safety ? Though MSDN documentation says that TraceSource is thread-safe and various methods such as TraceSource.TraceData(),TraceSource.TraceEvent() etc. also take thread-safety into consideration around all the trace listeners writing out trace logs.Since I'm planning to instantiate Logger class individually across each class in my web app as below.

```
   private ILogger log = new Logger("name of the source/class");
```

What would the best way to do so in a multi-threaded environment? Will using  a DI container like Ninject or Autofac make Logger class thread-safe or shall I create a singleton and use it or reuse it across the entire app to make it thread-safe. The problem that I'm facing if I create a singleton instance of Logger class is that I won't be able to pass a string as parameter to Logger class' non-default constructor and eventually the same string to TraceSource class to know the name of the source or component on the run or on the fly.

Some of you might say why am I re-inventing the wheels and creating a wrapper around TraceSource rather than using TraceSource directly as such. But as mentioned in the beginning of my question is that I want to have more control over what is being sent as a log to a file or database.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet- so would have asked why you're creating a custom logger rather than using NLog. If you did this then static log instances in NLog are threadsafe:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyClassName");
```

> Because loggers are thread-safe, you can simply create the logger once and store it in a static variable.

See more here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Nlog is highly configurable, and appears to be fit for purpose for the use case you described.

HTH

Comment: Well the thing is that we looked at Log4Net, Nlog etc. But none of these out of the box loggers insert logs to database.. All they do is to write the logs in files on hard disc. Correct me if I'm wrong, since that's what my understanding of these loggers is. To achieve what I need to achieve I also wrote a custom trace listener which is doing the job of inserting  logs to database

Comment: NLog can write to the db. Here's some info: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target

Comment: Cool, but still I have been instructed to write a custom logger and custom trace listener. So I need to stick to what I have been asked to do.